# don't want to dismiss UIPopover

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

i am using this following code to display a popover in my View

```
imagePopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc];
initWithContentViewController:self.photoLibraryImageCollection.imagePickerController];
imagePopOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(185,675);
imagePopOver.delegate = self;   
[imagePopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(600,0, 140, 800) 
                              inView:self.view 
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

it working fine however if we click any other part of myView ,this displayed popover is dismissing.can any one tell me how can i avoid this problem. i don't want to dismiss it at any time.can any one tell me how can do it.

Answer (score 7):

In the popover's delegate (your viewController, probably), implement

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    return NO;
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate!

Comment: thanks.....working.i can accept your answer only after 5 minutes.and also may i know how can i remove the Arrow from it.

Comment: there is a problem i am facing with these delegate .

i cant able to do any actions or any process in my View after i implemented this delegate.

so i am troubling with this problem .how can i avoid this problem with displaying my UIpopover.can any one tell me please.....

Comment: Hiding the arrow is possible by implementing your own `UIPopoverBackgroundView` subclass, but that's (relatively) a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

just wrote the below code at the time of popover initialization.

**myPopOver.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];**

in the above code will not dismiss your popOver and we can work with our View.

if you don't want to dismiss UIpopover only at the time of a textBox edit,simply write

**myPopOver.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.textBox];**